# PostMarkEmail response callback

Tags: postmark

I want to get the response from postmark that whether my email has been sent or not. Is there any way like few API's which provide the status callBack in Api that would automatically let our app know about the response which postmark would send for that email.

Comment: I've checked in my project reference there are two DLL's 1. PostmarkDotNet, 2. PostmarkEmail
I need to implement the tracking functionality of email to get the responses whether the email is being sent or not.

Answer (score 0):

While digging into the code I've found that PostmarkEmail is a wrapper of PostmarkDotNet which is being written by a developer to make sure we get the tasks done before the application stops.
The solution of the question is the bounceHooKURL given by the Postmark API, this can be configurable in the account. This event trigger when any email gets bounced and report the details as [PostmarkBonuce](http://developer.postmarkapp.com/developer-bounce-webhook.html) model (described in the postmark API).

and those emails which are not bounced we can assume that those were sent without any error. Bounce response will be returned after a approx 10-15min time delay on the server link you have given in the API setting.